# Installing ESXi 4.1 with just 2gb of memory?

Tags: vmware-esxi

I'm trying to get ESXi 4.1 installed on a computer with a single 2gb memory stick. During setup ESXi detects only the available memory (1.7gb), which is below the 2048mb that it requires. Is there anyway to tell it to skip the memory check?

Alternatively, if I install another stick just for installation, will it boot with less than 2gb of ram? This is just a home server I'm trying to install ESXi.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're available memory is only 1.7GB, it's probably because your system is using 256MB of system memory for the integrated video.  Perhaps if you drop a real PCIe video card (even PCI) you can disable the onboard video leaving the full 2GB available.  Really though, just buy more rams.

Answer (score 2):

You need at least 2gb of ram free.  On a system with exactly 2GB you will not have that much free as various system device will have mapped their devices into memory (typically video cards are the largest culprit)

Answer (score 0):

so I have the same issue.
after it fails it drops into toubleshooting mode and I chnage the 
RequiredMemory setting to 768000 (the real min) in /etc/vmware/init/init.d/00.vmnix

but I now I can't figure out how to start the install back up :(

---

Ha! turned off the vga memory in th bios and squeeked by!!!